# Running a monthly task in a .net shared webhosting environment

Tags: .net, page-lifecycle

I have a .net 4.5 web application (MVC 5) running in a shared hosting environment. I would like to run an automated task about once a month (with absolutely no accuracy required).

The app pool will be recycled after ~ 20 minutes of inactivity (the problems of using a background task in this type of environment are well described in this [article by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx/)).

It seems the easiest way to do this would be to check against a database if DateTime.Today >= NextScheduledTime field, and if so run the method & set the database NextScheduledTime for the following month.

It would be optimal to do this check +/- execute the method with no performance penalty for the current request - i.e. immediately after the response to the web request has been sent to the client.

Is there an event or other way I can hook into this part of the web request cycle (or any other erudite ideas as to how I can/should run a monthly task in an environment such as this)?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) Nuget package, and so far is working a very well in testing.